# Populating select using ajax json array

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have an application which needs to be integrated with SagePay (payment gateway).

There is a list of countries in ISO-3166-1 format [here](http://www.sm-technologies.co.uk/blog/sagepay-iso-country-list-countrycodes-js/) which I want to add.

The list appears to be json data inside an array called `countries`:

```
countries = [
    {code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"},
    {code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan"},
    {code: "AX", name: "Aland Islands"},
    // ...
];
```

I have a `select` element with the ID `country`:

```
<select id="country"></select>
```

I have tried using ajax as follows to add these items to my `select` element on page load:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/js/countrycodes.js',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $('#country').append($('<option>').text(code).attr('value', name));
        });
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. If I `console.log(json)` in the `success` callback it doesn't produce anything.

I realise one issue is that the json data is inside an array, `countries`, but not sure how to parse this.

I've checked to make sure I'm getting a HTTP 200 on `/js/countrycodes.js` and this is accessible, as are the other files such as jQuery.

### Edit

This is the output if I run some of the suggested answers in my console:

```
        {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
        abort
        :
        ƒ (a)
        always
        :
        ƒ ()
        complete
        :
        ƒ ()
        done
        :
        ƒ ()
        error
        :
        ƒ ()
        fail
        :
        ƒ ()
        getAllResponseHeaders
        :
        ƒ ()
        getResponseHeader
        :
        ƒ (a)
        overrideMimeType
        :
        ƒ (a)
        pipe
        :
        ƒ ()
        progress
        :
        ƒ ()
        promise
        :
        ƒ (a)
        readyState
        :
        4
        responseText
        :
        "countries = [↵{code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"},↵{code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan"},↵{code: "AX", name: "Aland Islands"},↵{code: "AL", name: "Albania"},↵{code: "DZ", name: "Algeria"},↵{code: "AS", name: "American Samoa"},↵{code: "AD", name: "Andorra"},↵{code: "AO", name: "Angola"},↵{code: "AI", name: "Anguilla"},↵{code: "AQ", name: "Antarctica"},↵{code: "AG", name: "Antigua and Barbuda"},↵{code: "AR", name: "Argentina"},↵{code: "AM", name: "Armenia"},↵{code: "AW", name: "Aruba"},↵{code: "AU", name: "Australia"},↵{code: "AT", name: "Austria"},↵{code: "AZ", name: "Azerbaijan"},↵{code: "BS", name: "Bahamas"},↵{code: "BH", name: "Bahrain"},↵{code: "BD", name: "Bangladesh"},↵{code: "BB", name: "Barbados"},↵{code: "BY", name: "Belarus"},↵{code: "BE", name: "Belgium"},↵{code: "BZ", name: "Belize"},↵{code: "BJ", name: "Benin"},↵{code: "BM", name: "Bermuda"},↵{code: "BT", name: "Bhutan"},↵{code: "BO", name: "Bolivia"},↵{code: "BA", name: "Bosnia and Herzegovina"},↵{code: "BW", name: "Botswana"},↵{code: "BV", name: "Bouvet Island"},↵{code: "BR", name: "Brazil"},↵{code: "IO", name: "British Indian Ocean Territory"},↵{code: "BN", name: "Brunei Darussalam"},↵{code: "BG", name: "Bulgaria"},↵{code: "BF", name: "Burkina Faso"},↵{code: "BI", name: "Burundi"},↵{code: "KH", name: "Cambodia"},↵{code: "CM", name: "Cameroon"},↵{code: "CA", name: "Canada"},↵{code: "CV", name: "Cape Verde"},↵{code: "KY", name: "Cayman Islands"},↵{code: "CF", name: "Central African Republic"},↵{code: "TD", name: "Chad"},↵{code: "CL", name: "Chile"},↵{code: "CN", name: "China"},↵{code: "CX", name: "Christmas Island"},↵{code: "CC", name: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"},↵{code: "CO", name: "Colombia"},↵{code: "KM", name: "Comoros"},↵{code: "CG", name: "Congo"},↵{code: "CD", name: "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the"},↵{code: "CK", name: "Cook Islands"},↵{code: "CR", name: "Costa Rica"},↵{code: "CI", name: "Côte d'Ivoire"},↵{code: "HR", name: "Croatia"},↵{code: "CU", name: "Cuba"},↵{code: "CY", name: "Cyprus"},↵{code: "CZ", name: "Czech Republic"},↵{code: "DK", name: "Denmark"},↵{code: "DJ", name: "Djibouti"},↵{code: "DM", name: "Dominica"},↵{code: "DO", name: "Dominican Republic"},↵{code: "EC", name: "Ecuador"},↵{code: "EG", name: "Egypt"},↵{code: "SV", name: "El Salvador"},↵{code: "GQ", name: "Equatorial Guinea"},↵{code: "ER", name: "Eritrea"},↵{code: "EE", name: "Estonia"},↵{code: "ET", name: "Ethiopia"},↵{code: "FK", name: "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"},↵{code: "FO", name: "Faroe Islands"},↵{code: "FJ", name: "Fiji"},↵{code: "FI", name: "Finland"},↵{code: "FR", name: "France"},↵{code: "GF", name: "French Guiana"},↵{code: "PF", name: "French Polynesia"},↵{code: "TF", name: "French Southern Territories"},↵{code: "GA", name: "Gabon"},↵{code: "GM", name: "Gambia"},↵{code: "GE", name: "Georgia"},↵{code: "DE", name: "Germany"},↵{code: "GH", name: "Ghana"},↵{code: "GI", name: "Gibraltar"},↵{code: "GR", name: "Greece"},↵{code: "GL", name: "Greenland"},↵{code: "GD", name: "Grenada"},↵{code: "GP", name: "Guadeloupe"},↵{code: "GU", name: "Guam"},↵{code: "GT", name: "Guatemala"},↵{code: "GG", name: "Guernsey"},↵{code: "GN", name: "Guinea"},↵{code: "GW", name: "Guinea-Bissau"},↵{code: "GY", name: "Guyana"},↵{code: "HT", name: "Haiti"},↵{code: "HM", name: "Heard Island and McDonald Islands"},↵{code: "VA", name: "Holy See (Vatican City State)"},↵{code: "HN", name: "Honduras"},↵{code: "HK", name: "Hong Kong"},↵{code: "HU", name: "Hungary"},↵{code: "IS", name: "Iceland"},↵{code: "IN", name: "India"},↵{code: "ID", name: "Indonesia"},↵{code: "IR", name: "Iran, Islamic Republic of"},↵{code: "IQ", name: "Iraq"},↵{code: "IE", name: "Ireland"},↵{code: "IM", name: "Isle of Man"},↵{code: "IL", name: "Israel"},↵{code: "IT", name: "Italy"},↵{code: "JM", name: "Jamaica"},↵{code: "JP", name: "Japan"},↵{code: "JE", name: "Jersey"},↵{code: "JO", name: "Jordan"},↵{code: "KZ", name: "Kazakhstan"},↵{code: "KE", name: "Kenya"},↵{code: "KI", name: "Kiribati"},↵{code: "KP", name: "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of"},↵{code: "KR", name: "Korea, Republic of"},↵{code: "KW", name: "Kuwait"},↵{code: "KG", name: "Kyrgyzstan"},↵{code: "LA", name: "Lao People's Democratic Republic"},↵{code: "LV", name: "Latvia"},↵{code: "LB", name: "Lebanon"},↵{code: "LS", name: "Lesotho"},↵{code: "LR", name: "Liberia"},↵{code: "LY", name: "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya"},↵{code: "LI", name: "Liechtenstein"},↵{code: "LT", name: "Lithuania"},↵{code: "LU", name: "Luxembourg"},↵{code: "MO", name: "Macao"},↵{code: "MK", name: "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of"},↵{code: "MG", name: "Madagascar"},↵{code: "MW", name: "Malawi"},↵{code: "MY", name: "Malaysia"},↵{code: "MV", name: "Maldives"},↵{code: "ML", name: "Mali"},↵{code: "MT", name: "Malta"},↵{code: "MH", name: "Marshall Islands"},↵{code: "MQ", name: "Martinique"},↵{code: "MR", name: "Mauritania"},↵{code: "MU", name: "Mauritius"},↵{code: "YT", name: "Mayotte"},↵{code: "MX", name: "Mexico"},↵{code: "FM", name: "Micronesia, Federated States of"},↵{code: "MD", name: "Moldova"},↵{code: "MC", name: "Monaco"},↵{code: "MN", name: "Mongolia"},↵{code: "ME", name: "Montenegro"},↵{code: "MS", name: "Montserrat"},↵{code: "MA", name: "Morocco"},↵{code: "MZ", name: "Mozambique"},↵{code: "MM", name: "Myanmar"},↵{code: "NA", name: "Namibia"},↵{code: "NR", name: "Nauru"},↵{code: "NP", name: "Nepal"},↵{code: "NL", name: "Netherlands"},↵{code: "AN", name: "Netherlands Antilles"},↵{code: "NC", name: "New Caledonia"},↵{code: "NZ", name: "New Zealand"},↵{code: "NI", name: "Nicaragua"},↵{code: "NE", name: "Niger"},↵{code: "NG", name: "Nigeria"},↵{code: "NU", name: "Niue"},↵{code: "NF", name: "Norfolk Island"},↵{code: "MP", name: "Northern Mariana Islands"},↵{code: "NO", name: "Norway"},↵{code: "OM", name: "Oman"},↵{code: "PK", name: "Pakistan"},↵{code: "PW", name: "Palau"},↵{code: "PS", name: "Palestinian Territory, Occupied"},↵{code: "PA", name: "Panama"},↵{code: "PG", name: "Papua New Guinea"},↵{code: "PY", name: "Paraguay"},↵{code: "PE", name: "Peru"},↵{code: "PH", name: "Philippines"},↵{code: "PN", name: "Pitcairn"},↵{code: "PL", name: "Poland"},↵{code: "PT", name: "Portugal"},↵{code: "PR", name: "Puerto Rico"},↵{code: "QA", name: "Qatar"},↵{code: "RE", name: "Réunion"},↵{code: "RO", name: "Romania"},↵{code: "RU", name: "Russian Federation"},↵{code: "RW", name: "Rwanda"},↵{code: "BL", name: "Saint Barthélemy"},↵{code: "SH", name: "Saint Helena"},↵{code: "KN", name: "Saint Kitts and Nevis"},↵{code: "LC", name: "Saint Lucia"},↵{code: "MF", name: "Saint Martin"},↵{code: "PM", name: "Saint Pierre and Miquelon"},↵{code: "VC", name: "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"},↵{code: "WS", name: "Samoa"},↵{code: "SM", name: "San Marino"},↵{code: "ST", name: "Sao Tome and Principe"},↵{code: "SA", name: "Saudi Arabia"},↵{code: "SN", name: "Senegal"},↵{code: "RS", name: "Serbia"},↵{code: "SC", name: "Seychelles"},↵{code: "SL", name: "Sierra Leone"},↵{code: "SG", name: "Singapore"},↵{code: "SK", name: "Slovakia"},↵{code: "SI", name: "Slovenia"},↵{code: "SB", name: "Solomon Islands"},↵{code: "SO", name: "Somalia"},↵{code: "ZA", name: "South Africa"},↵{code: "GS", name: "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"},↵{code: "ES", name: "Spain"},↵{code: "LK", name: "Sri Lanka"},↵{code: "SD", name: "Sudan"},↵{code: "SR", name: "Suriname"},↵{code: "SJ", name: "Svalbard and Jan Mayen"},↵{code: "SZ", name: "Swaziland"},↵{code: "SE", name: "Sweden"},↵{code: "CH", name: "Switzerland"},↵{code: "SY", name: "Syrian Arab Republic"},↵{code: "TW", name: "Taiwan, Province of China"},↵{code: "TJ", name: "Tajikistan"},↵{code: "TZ", name: "Tanzania, United Republic of"},↵{code: "TH", name: "Thailand"},↵{code: "TL", name: "Timor-Leste"},↵{code: "TG", name: "Togo"},↵{code: "TK", name: "Tokelau"},↵{code: "TO", name: "Tonga"},↵{code: "TT", name: "Trinidad and Tobago"},↵{code: "TN", name: "Tunisia"},↵{code: "TR", name: "Turkey"},↵{code: "TM", name: "Turkmenistan"},↵{code: "TC", name: "Turks and Caicos Islands"},↵{code: "TV", name: "Tuvalu"},↵{code: "UG", name: "Uganda"},↵{code: "UA", name: "Ukraine"},↵{code: "AE", name: "United Arab Emirates"},↵{code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"},↵{code: "US", name: "United States"},↵{code: "UM", name: "United States Minor Outlying Islands"},↵{code: "UY", name: "Uruguay"},↵{code: "UZ", name: "Uzbekistan"},↵{code: "VU", name: "Vanuatu"},↵{code: "VE", name: "Venezuela"},↵{code: "VN", name: "Viet Nam"},↵{code: "VG", name: "Virgin Islands, British"},↵{code: "VI", name: "Virgin Islands, U.S."},↵{code: "WF", name: "Wallis and Futuna"},↵{code: "EH", name: "Western Sahara"},↵{code: "YE", name: "Yemen"},↵{code: "ZM", name: "Zambia"},↵{code: "ZW", name: "Zimbabwe"}↵];"
        setRequestHeader
        :
        ƒ (a,b)
        state
        :
        ƒ ()
        status
        :
        200
        statusCode
        :
        ƒ (a)
        statusText
        :
        "OK"
        success
        :
        ƒ ()
        then
        :
        ƒ ()
        __proto__
        :
        Object
```

Comment: Andy do you have any error in your browser console with your original code?

Comment: @AlivetoDie No. I've posted what I get even when I run some of the suggested answers in my Console. I can see the data in `responseText` but it won't update my `select`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an alternative: since your country list is static and contained in a .js file which declares it as a variable, it can just be included in your page in the normal way, without the need for ajax:

```
<select id="country"></select>
<script type="javascript" language="text/javascript" src="/js/countrycodes.js"></script>
<script>
//use the countries variable which was declared in the countrycodes script file.
$.each(countries, function(i, value) {
  $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value.code).attr('value', value.name));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: countries is not defined. I'll look into it. Something very very weird is happening with this today!

Comment: certainly is. It works fine in my sandbox. Are you sure countrycodes.js is loading correctly?

Comment: It's working now. I've no idea what's happened - possibly some weird caching issue as I'm using ExpressionEngine. I've created a fiddle to test it and it works fine. Made a slight amendment to get the country name `value.name` as the option text: https://jsfiddle.net/eb8ydh4n/. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/js/countrycodes.js',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $('#country').append($('<option>').text(value.code).attr('value', value.name));
        });
    }
});
```

should fix it. You simply missed `value.` to reference the properties within the current object in the loop. In your version `code` and `name` haven't come from anywhere. They don't acquire their values automatically, instead they are properties of `value`.

Comment: Ok. Something strange is going on because it just does nothing. Even if I run it directly in the Console I get `{readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}` and can see the `responseText` with the data in it. But it just won't populate the `select` at all. I've checked the ID (`#country`) is spelt right and that in my code it's inside `document.ready`. What else could it be, or how else can I debug this?

Comment: what command produces that output exactly? What does doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(json));` at the start of the "success" function produce?

Comment: It doesn't produce anything. Tried in Chrome 60.0.3112.101 and Firefox 54.0.1. jQuery version is 1.12.3 and is loaded correctly (HTTP 200).

Comment: can you try changing from POST to GET? Doesn't make much sense to POST to a static file from which you want to retrieve (get) information. Also, I just noticed that responseText contains actual Javascript, not JSON. i.e. the file contains code not data. It should just start immediately with `[{ code...` etc, not with `countries = ` - ajax can't interpret that as JSON, it's not valid. Of course, since this is a static list, you could just include countries.js into your script in the normal way and just create the`<select>` options from it directly, and remove the ajax part entirely

Comment: there doesn't seem much point retrieving this via delayed ajax request when the list doesn't change, and you've got the info in a .js file already. You could just do it at page load very simply.

Comment: please post code or clarify how to do that. It sounds good to me but I've no idea how to implement it! I changed POST to GET which made no difference, and also changed the syntax of the json as per your suggestion; again this does not affect it.

Comment: something else is going on then, because that should work fine. But I'll post the alternative as a new answer