# PHP - json_decode giving NULL

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to use the advice given in [How to search through a JSON Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987611/how-to-search-through-a-json-array-in-php) to lookup country names based on a country code in a .json file.

I have a file, `countrycodes.js` which is formatted like this:

```
countries = [
    {code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"},
    {code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan"},
    // ...
    {code: "ZM", name: "Zambia"},
    {code: "ZW", name: "Zimbabwe"}
];
```

The variable, `countries` has to be there because part of the application relies on this.

In PHP I've done the following:

```
$str = file_get_contents('countrycodes.js');
var_dump($str);
```

This outputs a string:

```
string(9642) "countries = [
{code: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"},
{code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan"},
// ...
```

However, when I try and `json_decode` it, the following gives `NULL`:

```
$str = file_get_contents('countrycodes.js');
$json = json_decode($str);
var_dump($json);
```

I don't know why this is because `json_decode` accepts a string, and this is what's given on the link I posted above? I tried removing the JavaScript variable (`countries =` ) but this made no difference.

Ultimately what I want to do is be able to give PHP a country `code` such as 'GB' and get it to return the appropriate `name` e.g. 'United Kingdom'. My understanding of this is the `json_decode` part will need to work before this is possible.

*For reference, the reason `countries =`  was being used is for populating a `<select>` element based on advice given here: [Populating select using ajax json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795518/populating-select-using-ajax-json-array/45797083)*

Comment: `countrycodes.js` is Javascript, not JSON...

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there any ways to convert it, without having to store it in 2 separate files?

Comment: No way that is sane.

Comment: i wonder that json formatting have a syntax error inside the file!

Comment: try passing true as the second parameter

Comment: @RahulMeshram Really? It's not JSON :P

Comment: @Andy It may be worth considering reversing what you've got. Having the countries in a DB, and using AJAX to get the JSON _from_ the PHP.

Comment: If you were to explain why you think you must keep the `countries =` maybe we can suggest a solution that would make that valid JSON and work in your other code

Comment: @JonStirling : I didn't said anything like this

Comment: @RahulMeshram Huh? Passing `true` to `json_decode` isn't going to help if the input isn't valid JSON.

Comment: The link which I'd given - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795518/populating-select-using-ajax-json-array/45797083 - was where I'd asked about how to populate a `select` element based on `countrycodes.js`. I can reformat the file so it's JSON as per the Answer given below. However, that will break my `select` element. I don't want to store the countries in a DB because this file (countrycodes.js) comes from a third party and it's easier to just take a copy of it than update a DB of the same data. Confused as to what @CBroe means.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. I've been given an Answer now which I've accepted. I've changed the format of my file and am going to look into `$.getJSON()` as suggested to populate the select. Apologies if I've approached populating the select the wrong way, however that solution was given by someone with a 9k reputation here on SO, and it did actually work for that particular problem at the time. I've only noticed it because I'm trying to implement this thing now to lookup the country name from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `json_decode` returns `null`, this means the input string is not in a valid format. Your file contains a javascript variable and not a JSON string.

This is how the string should probably formatted:

```
{
    "countries": [
        {"code": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"},
        {"code": "AF", "name": "Afghanistan"},
        {"code": "ZM", "name": "Zambia"},
        {"code": "ZW", "name": "Zimbabwe"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can reformat the file so it looks like that. However this will inevitably break what I'd  had  a hard time implementing to populate a `select` element based on the file contents - details are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795518/populating-select-using-ajax-json-array/45797083. So is it possible to populate a `select` based on the format you've given? I'm trying to think of a solution which will cover both requirements. Thanks.

Comment: That is not a very good solution in javascript. You should look at the [`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) function to get the json file at the client side.

Comment: @Jerodev can you confirm that that's how the string *should* be formatted? Because it's still giving `NULL` as the output when `json_decode()`-ing that.

Comment: This is most certainly a valid json string. Please update your answer with your new string so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: My fault. When I'd enclosed `code` and `name` in quotes I'd put the colon inside the string! It's fixed now. Thanks for your patience/help.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Jerodev's answer, if you <strike>cannot</strike> will not change the representation, you could do the following.

Modify your file so that you wrap the keys with quotes. Something like,

```
countries = [
    {"code": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"},
    {"code": "AF", "name": "Afghanistan"},
    // ...
    {"code": "ZM", "name": "Zambia"},
    {"code": "ZW", "name": "Zimbabwe"}
];
```

And then just decode the json part.

```
$str = file_get_contents('countrycodes.js');
$str = substr($str,12, strlen($str)-13); // do not include the semicolon
var_dump(json_decode($str));
```

However this is not a good approach, so I'd still suggest to look for other ways to populate the data in your element.

Note that `12` is the position where `[` starts, if you have made any changes to variable names or spaces, that (and `13`) needs to change.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more than happy to reformat the file as per Jerodev's suggestion. This problem has originated from advice I was given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795518/populating-select-using-ajax-json-array/45797083 from someone who had a 9k reputation, and their solution seemed to work for that particular problem. I'm going to reformat my file and look into `$.getJSON()` as suggested by @Jerodev.

Comment: Cool. Good choice!